# ConstraintLayout not displayed in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-databinding

For my application, I had to create my own widget because our designer was looking for a fancy animation. The overall code works but I am looking to use data binding instead of `findViewById` but it seems not displaying the layout when asks. below is the code:

```
class MyEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    private var binding: EditTextMyBinding

    private lateinit var hint: String
    private lateinit var defaultError: String

    fun setCustomView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?) {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_edit_text, container, false)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)
        setupView()
    }

    ...
```

This widget is used in a fragment_login.xml like this:

```
<com.xxx.yyy.ui.widgets.MyEditText
            android:id="@+id/userEmailEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />
```

and the fragement.kt is using it below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        emailField = binding.userEmailEt
        setCustomView(inflater, container)
```

it seems that it's not enough to make it appears. Any idea how to display the MyEditText properly using data binding ?

Comment: Does the whole layout doesn't show or only the `EditText`?

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0 Only the MyEditText

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0 login layout shows up but the R.layout.my_edit_text is not showing

Comment: What is in `setupView()`? It looks like that, even though you create the view, you don't add it to the _ConstraintLayout_. Use the Layout Inspector to see if your view is in the hierarchy. I will bet it is not and needs to be added.

Comment: @Cheticamp setupView just add clicklistner stuff like that

Comment: Ok. In setCustomView add `addView(view)` to see if your view appears. If it does appear, you will still need to set its constraints.